# Add minutes and seconds. Display in hours

Tags: c++, boost-units

Let's suppose I'd like to add 29 minutes and 60 seconds and display the result in hours.

Here's something that appears to work:

```
cout <<
    static_cast<quantity<hour_base_unit::unit_type>>
    (quantity<time>{29.0 * minute_base_unit::unit_type()} + 60.0 * seconds)
    << endl;
```

The following is displayed on the console:

```
0.5 h
```

Is this the recommended approach? Is there a better or more idiomatic way?

The entire program illustrating the above example is below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/units/systems/si/io.hpp>
#include <boost/units/systems/si.hpp>
#include <boost/units/base_units/metric/hour.hpp>
#include <boost/units/base_units/metric/minute.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::units;
using namespace boost::units::si;
using namespace boost::units::metric;

int main()
{   
    cout <<
        static_cast<quantity<hour_base_unit::unit_type>>
        (quantity<time>{29.0 * minute_base_unit::unit_type()} + 60.0 * seconds)
        << endl;        

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do

(minutes/60+seconds/3600)