# Define minutes unit

Tags: c++, boost, boost-units

Here's a bit of code from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34385537/add-minutes-and-seconds-display-in-hours) which adds 29.0 minutes to 60.0 seconds and displays the result in hours:

```
cout <<
    static_cast<quantity<hour_base_unit::unit_type>>
    (quantity<time>{29.0 * minute_base_unit::unit_type()} + 60.0 * seconds)
    << endl;
```

What's the recommended way to define `minutes` so that the above expression can be written as:

```
cout <<
    static_cast<quantity<hour_base_unit::unit_type>>
    (29.0 * minutes + 60.0 * seconds)
    << endl;
```

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/boost/units/systems/si/time.hpp seems important

Answer (score 2):

If you can, I would recommend using C++14's `<chrono>` facilities for this. They are very nice.  (I know this is not technically an answer to his question, but it might save him a lot of work).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main () {
    using namespace std::chrono;
    std::cout << duration_cast<hours>(29min + 60s).count() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Hi Marshall! `chrono` is definitely very nice. However, I just used "hours, minutes, seconds" as they're familiar units. I'd like to do things similar to the above for other sorts of units (add feet + meters, see the result in inches, etc). (PS: I enjoyed the 2014 Grill the Committe presentation!)